# How to deploy django backend from subfolder of github repository in Railway?

Tags: django, deployment, backend, web-deployment

I have created a project where I have my django backend and nextjs frontend in the same repository in different folders, I want to know if there is a way to deply my django backend from its subfolder and not have to make a separate repository for my backend.

I put my requirements.txt, runtime.txt and Procfile in the root folder and made the Procfile point to backend.myblog.wsgi but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in the settings of the railway deployment under the Service section where you can specify the root directory which by default is set to "/".

I changed that to "/backend" and it worked!

[image: specify root directory setting]